# Embed blenderplayer in a window PyQt

Tags: blender, pyqt5

I have been trying to embed blenderplayer in a window PyQt5 but i receive two windows instead of one windows PyQt embed blender player.
Could you help me please to achieve my gol please?
this is my script:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
from PyQt5.QtGui import QWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QPushButton, QFrame

class embedBlender(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumWidth(800)
        self.setMinimumHeight(600)
        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton('button'))
        self.process = QProcess(self)
        # -i Window_ID -w Width Height X Y
        self.process.start(' '.join(('blenderplayer -i', str(self.frame.winId().__int__()), '-w 400 400 c:\V2.blend')))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = embedBlender()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You may know that blender leans heavily on a single window interface and this carries into the game engine. The `-i` option for blenderplayer sets a parentwindowID - this is not the same as a containing window for the player to use as it's main display.

If you follow the code through, you will find that a new window will be created and on [X11 it's parent is set to be the windowID](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowX11.cpp;6f1493f68fe01a8e951cf6c4e50103e20b85d513$394) you pass in. On windows, again the new window is created and [it's input device](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowWin32.cpp;6f1493f68fe01a8e951cf6c4e50103e20b85d513$253) is set to the input used by the parent window. So the option doesn't do what you are expecting.

I don't think that blender will do what you are trying without you altering and building your own copy of blender.

Just a theory but blender (not blenderplayer) has a `--window-borderless` option - you might be able to start blender without window borders, positioned in the right place so that it is located over the area you want it to be without any visual distinction. You can use a startup script to enable the game engine and start playing. Of course you will have issues with the game window falling behind the main window and not moving with it.

The other way is to use blender entirely, that is use a layout that places the game where you want and [customise blender's interface](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Panel.html) to create what you want around it. As an example at the extreme end, look at [Fluid Designer](https://www.microvellum.com/solutions/fluid-designer/) - it uses blender but has adjusted the UI to make it into a unique application.

Comment: thank you for reply. When i saw thoss links: , i think it's feasible to do it but Something missing in my code...